# POST method not allowed on custom Drupal 8 REST resource

Tags: drupal

I've created a custom `RestResource`, it kind of looks like this:

```
/**
 * Provides a resource to get/create content data.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "arcelor_content",
 *   label = @Translation("Arcelor content"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/content/{type}"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ContentResource extends ResourceBase {

    public function get($type) {
        // Works
    }

    public function post($type) {
        // Doesn't work
    }
}
```

I've enabled the resource and set the permissions in RestUI.

The GET method works fine, but when I try to post I get this error:

```
{
"message": "No route found for \"POST /api/content/buffer\": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)"
}
```

Method not allowed! Even though the permissions have been set, post has been enabled, the cache has been flushed a million times, ...

I came across [a question on the drupal site](https://www.drupal.org/node/2512646) that said it could be fixed by adding another uri_path to the phpdoc tag, so I did:

```
/**
 * Provides a resource to get/create content data.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "arcelor_content",
 *   label = @Translation("Arcelor content"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/content/{type}",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/api/content/{type}"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

Unfortunately that did nothing, and I still get the "not allowed" error.

So, does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: You could solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

2 things were causing the "not allowed" problem:

1. POST methods require the `Content-Type` header to be set to `application/hal+json`, that's the only thing they will accept. Even if you plan to do something different with regular JSON data, you'll have to work around this somehow (which I failed to do)
2. POST methods also require the `X-CSRF-Token` header to be set, you can get a token by going to `/rest/session/token`

Now I am no longer getting the "not allowed" error! Unfortunately, because the body needs to be `hal+json`, I'm getting an `"A fatal error occurred: Class does not exist"` error now.

Answer (score 2):

For me, under Drupal 8.2.6, what solve the problem of *Method not allowed* for POST is that I forget to specify the create URI in the resource definition annotation:

```
/**
 * Provides a resource for clients subscription to updates.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "updates_subscription",
 *   label = @Translation("Updates subscription"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/updates-subscription",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/api/updates-subscription"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

The fact is that if you forget to specify the `"https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create"` URI path, Drupal defaults to the resource id path, `updates_subscription` in this case.

You can read this [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview), in the *Creating REST resource plugins* section.

No need for `application/hal+json` content type neither to use a `X-CSRF-Token`.